# Do non-clustered (non-PK) indexes need to include clustered (PK) columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

For example, here are 2 indexes on `FOO` table:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FOO] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_FOO] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FOO] 
    ON [dbo].[FOO] ([id] ASC, [a] ASC, [b] ASC)
```

Many queries are using `IX_FOO` when filtering with `a` column. And it seems `id` column in `IX_FOO` is redundant since `PK_FOO` is indexing it. So I'm thinking to remove `id` column from `IX_FOO` like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_FOO2] 
    ON [dbo].[FOO] ([a] ASC, [b] ASC) 
    INCLUDE ([id])
```

But I'm not sure myself. Do indexes need to include PK columns?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I'm thinking to remove `id` column from `IX_FOO` since `PK_FOO` already indexing it. But I'm not sure if this is a rational idea.

Comment: Makes sense to me, but I'm not a SQL expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of columns in index is important.

Index on `(ID, a, b)` is very different to index on `(a, b) include (id)`.

The first index on `(ID, a, b)` can be used when searching by:

1. ID, a, b: `WHERE ID = 1 AND a = 2 AND b = 3`
2. ID, a, range of b: `WHERE ID = 1 AND a = 2 AND b > 3 AND b < 5`
3. ID, a: `WHERE ID = 1 AND a = 2`
4. ID, range of a: `WHERE ID = 1 AND a > 2 AND a < 5`
5. ID: `WHERE ID = 1`
6. range of ID: `WHERE ID > 1 AND ID < 5`

This index will **not** be used when searching just for `a` or just for `b`: `WHERE a = 2`; `WHERE b = 3`.

Selected columns can be any combination of `ID`, `a`, `b` - if there are more columns, index would be not enough and engine would have to read them from the table.

---

The second index on `(a, b) include (id)` can be used when searching by:

1. a, b: `WHERE a = 2 AND b = 3`
2. a, range of b: `WHERE a = 2 AND b > 3 AND b < 5`
3. a: `WHERE a = 2`
4. range of a: `WHERE a > 2 AND a < 5`

This index will **not** be used when searching just for `ID` or just for `b`: `WHERE ID = 1`; `WHERE b = 3`.

Selected columns also can be any combination of `ID`, `a`, `b` - if there are more columns, index would be not enough and engine would have to read them from the table.

---

If there is a clustered index on `ID`, then there is no point adding `ID` as `INCLUDE` to non-clustered index, because the clustered column is included in each non-clustered index implicitly. This is why it is generally recommended to have narrow clustered index, usually 4-byte `int`. The wider the clustered index, the more space is needed for each non-clustered index.

So, index on `(a, b) include (id)` is the same as `(a, b)` in your case.

I'm not sure if engine is smart enough to not waste disk space if you `INCLUDE ID` explicitly. It is easy to check.

Comment: Question about `WHERE ID = 1 AND a > 2 AND a < 5`: Is index like `IX_FOO` necessary for this search? I thought `PK_FOO` would be sufficient since `id` is unique and checking a range of `a` is not expensive. Maybe there is a caveat?

Comment: @user2652379, You are right, I wasn't thinking about `PK_FOO`, I was focusing on the difference between two variants on the non-clustered index. With `ID` being unique it doesn't matter which index to use `PK_FOO` or `IX_FOO`. Taking into account uniqueness of `ID` it doesn't make sense to have `IX_FOO` defined as it is. It is pretty much useless. All searches listed above that can be done efficiently with `IX_FOO` can be done with the same efficiency using `PK_FOO` when `ID` is unique.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't. Non Clustered indexes will be pointing to the primary key of the main table hence there is no need to add it (Primary Key) to any non clustered index.

In other words all non clustered indexes implicitly includes the clustered index of the table.